# UITextView number of lines iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

In iOS 6 I used this code to get the number of lines in the `UITextView`:

```
int numLines = textView.contentSize.height / textView.font.lineHeight;
```

But this is not working in iOS 7. How do I get the total number of lines of the UITextView in iOS 7?

Comment: have a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19028743/ios7-uitextview-contentsize-height-alternative/19067476#19067476

Comment: Possible duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837348/counting-the-number-of-lines-in-a-textview-lines-wrapped-by-frame-size

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counting the number of lines in a UITextView, lines wrapped by frame size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837348/counting-the-number-of-lines-in-a-uitextview-lines-wrapped-by-frame-size)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find UITextView number of lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320361/how-to-find-uitextview-number-of-lines)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like this. It's low performance but this is what I could figure till now.

```
NSString *string=textView3.text;
NSArray *array=[string componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
NSLog(@"%d",array.count);
```

Comment: This only counts line-breaks, and not line-wraps, unless your UITextView is so wide that no wrapping takes place.

Comment: How could one get a line count while accounting for wrapping?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with the `UITextInputTokenizer`/`UITextInput` protocol methods of UITextView.

```
id<UITextInputTokenizer> tokenizer = textView.tokenizer;
UITextPosition *pos = textView.endOfDocument; int lines = 0;

while (true){
    UITextPosition *lineEnd = [tokenizer positionFromPosition:pos toBoundary:UITextGranularityLine inDirection:UITextStorageDirectionBackward];

    if([textView comparePosition:pos toPosition:lineEnd] == NSOrderedSame){
        pos = [tokenizer positionFromPosition:lineEnd toBoundary:UITextGranularityCharacter inDirection:UITextStorageDirectionBackward];

        if([textView comparePosition:pos toPosition:lineEnd] == NSOrderedSame) break;

        continue;
    }

    lines++; pos = lineEnd;
}

//lines--; // Compensation for extra line calculated (??)
```

([GIST](https://gist.github.com/matt-curtis/f9efbd2c2df1b77e3471))

Comment: @JasonTyler I wonder why in my tests there was an extra line. Glad it worked for you, though.

Comment: probably you are testing on iPhone 6+ right? @mattsven?

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the String and textView to this method and it will return the current number 
rows in this textview even if the user pressed new line:

```
-(int)numberOfRows:(NSString *)string inView:(UITextView*)txtView
{

CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(MAXFLOAT , MAXFLOAT);

NSStringDrawingOptions options = NSStringDrawingTruncatesLastVisibleLine |
NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin;

NSString *new = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"\n" withString:@" "];
NSDictionary *attr = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:urFont size:urSize]};
CGRect bounds = [new boundingRectWithSize:maximumLabelSize
                                          options:options
                                       attributes:attr
                                          context:nil];

CGSize viewSize = bounds.size;


int row = floor(txtView.contentSize.height / viewSize.height ) ;


return row;
}
```