# Get number of lines UITextView without using "\n"?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I have a textView that I need the number of lines for, or the sizeToFit before it becomes sizeToFit.  I've tried checking for number of line breaks "\n" in the textView.  However, the text in the textView has been parsed bc it was pretty messy coming from the server with tons of html codes and awful line breaks that I had to use replaceOccurence of "\n" to remove the line breaks to make the text into one nice paragraph.

```
var rawString = self.selectedProduct.description   
var cleanString = rawString?.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\n", withString: " ", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
```

This code, of course, will only return 1 after the above code.

```
let desString = self.descriptionTextView.text
let numLines = desString.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
println(numLines.count)
```

This code, crashes.

```
 let numLines = self.descriptionTextView.contentSize.height / self.descriptionTextView.font.leading
```

Ultimately, what I want to partially show the text and have a button that reveals all the text.

Thanks

Comment: numLines = textView.contentSize.height/textView.font.lineHeight
check it plz

Comment: you can also check it.
UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11.0];
CGSize size = [string sizeWithFont:font 
                      constrainedToSize:myUITextView.frame.size 
                      lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap]; // default mode
float numberOfLines = size.height / font.lineHeight;

Comment: Interesting.  Your first solution crashes with "found nil unwrapping optional value" error...it does give a decimal of 3.0XX everytime.  I'm having a hard time with the 2nd solution in swift.

Comment: @TuanAnhVu thats because sizeWithFont is depreciated. sizeWithAttributes is the replacement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find UITextView number of lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320361/how-to-find-uitextview-number-of-lines)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have converted @aBilal17's comment to non depreciated stuff and swift.

```
// This gives you the size of that string

let font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(11)
let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
style.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
let size = someString.sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: font, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: style])
```

I use this extension I made to get the size of a string restrained to width:

```
extension String {
    func sizeForWidth(width: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGSize {
        let attr = [NSFontAttributeName: font]
        let height = NSString(string: self).boundingRectWithSize(CGSize(width: width, height: CGFloat.max), options:.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: attr, context: nil).height
        return CGSize(width, ceil(height))
    }
}
```

---

So In your case you can do:

```
let numLines = desString.sizeForWidth(descriptionTextView.contentSize.width, font: descriptionTextView.font).height / descriptionTextView.font.lineHeight
```

Comment: thanks! but i get a "Cannot assign to LineBreakMode in Style" error.  When i comment out style.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping, my size.height equals to 13.123 every time, not matter how much text i have.

Comment: I did like this in playground and it works: `let textView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 100))
textView.text = "AAds asd adasdasd asd assa sss asasas asasdd  ddd dass asdasd asdasd"
let numLines = Int(textView.text.sizeForWidth(textView.contentSize.width, font: textView.font).height / textView.font.lineHeight)`